# Is there a smarter way of doing this CSS columns JS replacement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, math

So my app consists of little squares (fixed size) that float left. When the number of columns' width and spacing match up with the window size, it looks great.

```
 | [] [] [] [] |
```

When it does not, there's a large space at the right side.

```
 | [] [] [] []   |
```

I tried to fix this using CSS columns which will display your content from the top downwards. I want left to right.

So I emulated left-to-right column behaviour with some javascript, basically taking the leftover width from the difference between the total width of the columns and the width of the container. I think what I really want is to find an elegant way of getting the number of columns.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var totalGridWidth = $("#grid").width();
    var videoWidth = $(".square").width();

    var spaceRatio = (totalGridWidth-scrollbarWidth)/videoWidth;
    var currCols = parseInt((spaceRatio).toString().split(".")[0]);
    var colLeftOverSpace = parseFloat("0."+(spaceRatio).toString().split(".")[1]);
    var num = colLeftOverSpace * (videoWidth/currCols);

    $(".square").css("margin-right", num/2 +"px").css("margin-left", num/2 +"px");
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ra3t2gub/ (resize the width)

Is there a more elegant way to do this? I'm a bit embarrassed of it.

Comment: Have you tried using floats with fluid (percentage) widths that can equally space out columns? Or do you mean you want fixed widths on the boxes that fill up the window width with spaces between them?

Comment: Yes, the boxes have are a fixed number of pixels wide.

Comment: Cool :) I saw words like "video" in your code. Is it for media objects like videos?

Comment: It's for this little project I've been fiddling with: http://instadj.com :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)! (while you read that, I'll be writing a more in depth answer)

Here is a pretty simple example while you're waiting - [Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/JordanForeman/pen/xbGrNE)

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #CCC;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks – space-around and wrap does almost exactly what I want. (Last row children are centered if the number of columns doesn't match the rest)

Comment: I take that back. I just had to use space-between. Thanks for this, Jordan.

Comment: Np :) glad I could help get you on the right track!